# What is typical Servlet + JSP + JDBC simple application architecture?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jdbc, architecture

When using Servlets & JSP in simple application, with database connection through DataSource/Connection pool, what is the typical application architecture?

1. when Connection object is created, is it common app's servlets
   superclass and passed by argument to doGet/doPost?
2. how Connection object is passed to DAO classes to retreive/update state of domain
   objects?
3. are SQL exceptions handled at DAO level, specific servlet level or servlet's superclass?
4. How are website templates designed? by JSP `include` tag?
5. Are DAO objects attibutes in specific servlet constructed when it is first instantiated or lay in another layer like created in doGet/doPost method?
6. Should every small operation in DAO retreive connection from DataSource or better pass Connection in DAO's constructor?
7. Is all data passed to JSP by request.setAttribute or there is a better way?
8. Should I only pass to JSP domain objects/collections or pass whole DAO/another mediator for data retreival?
9. Should we achieve only single Connection object for whole request-response chain? If yes, how to achieve that?

Comment: That's a lot of questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1) A pool of connections will be available as soon as the server is started,for this we need  to specify "Resource" tag in the "context.xml".Intially 10 connections will be available (default).

2)You can pass connection object,below example will give some you clarity

```
    class A {
    public static DataSource getConnection() {
     Context initContext  = new InitialContext();
     Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
     DataSource dataSource = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/testdb");
     return dataSource;
    }
     }  
   class B {
    javax.sql.DataSource ds=(DataSource)A.getConnection();
    javax.sql.Connection con=ds.getConnection();
    }
```

3)you can derive your own exceptions or pre-defined exceptions it depends on the use-case.
  Generally exceptions are handled in any level or you can suppress  in some way.

4)In jsp ,jsp:include using  is the best way.because,include have its own disadvantages.

5)Iam not clear about your 5th question

6)constructor level is best ,i hope or you create a separate connection class do exceptions handling,connections closing and passage in that.it will look great.

7)you have three scopes:application ,request  and session.Dont use request.setAttribute for everything.it has some limits.

8)passing data in the form of collections is easy to handle.

9)Iam not aware of that.

note:If you find any mistakes,dont mind